# Can a Timeframe be inserted in other timeframes without overlapping

Tags: java

I'm having a TimeFrame class like this:

```
class TimeFrame {
    private LocalDateTime startTime;
    private LocalDateTime endTime;
}
```

Now I have a List of TimeFrames. I know want to check if I can insert a new TimeFrame in the list so that the times DO NOT overlap. Taken into account the dayStart and dayEnd time (constants during the whole app).

I'm having a hard time implementing this and I seems to me it can be done easier.

Can someone help me out and point me to the right direction.

Comment: Take a look at [Guava's Ranges](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained) - this problem has already been [solved](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html)!

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. Actually my question is now do I need to figure out myself where I can put the timeframe or does guava has a method to find the timeframe?

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation I linked? It answers your question. For example [`RangeSet.intersects`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html#intersects-com.google.common.collect.Range-) already does what you ask **without looping**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Boris The Spider.

Use Guava to solve the problem.

Step 1 create a Range for every timeframe like this:

```
 LocalDateTime startTime;
 LocalDateTime endTime;
 Range.closedOpen(startTime, endTime);
```

Step 2 create a RangeSet:

```
RangeSet rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create(ranges);
```

Step 3 see if the target date intersects the ranges:

```
rangeSet.intersects(targetTimeFrame.timerange)
```